# How to search in Ubuntu/Linux using two different date?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logs, date, time

Please assist. I am trying to search few events in `Ubuntu` from `auth.log` and `syslog` in `/var/log/` folder using two different date range, how can I do it?

My Code is like below with only one date range but I need Start date and End date in it:

```
#!/bin/bash

#User Input
echo -n -e "What's your Date range:"
read inputdate

#Save the search result in a file
sudo egrep "$inputdate" /var/log/auth.log > result.txt

#Display the result column wise with highlighted searching key word
column -t result.txt | more

echo -e "---------* End of Search Result! *-----------"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For such questions you should always provide example input and output.

Comment: Input: 1) User Input Start date: 21/06/2020 or 21-06-2020                                                    
         2)User Input End date: 22/06/2020 or 22-06-2020                                                              Output:  Should display all event logs based on this range

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the example input and expected output. Make sure to use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and format it as code so we can read it easily.

Comment: I have done little change hope it will work.

Comment: Just use `sed`: `sed -n '/StartPattern/,/EndPattern/p' FileName`

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Panki's suggestion, the script would then look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#User Input
echo -n -e "What's your start date: "
read startdate
echo -n -e "What's your end date: "
read enddate

#Save the search result in a file
sed -n "/$startdate/,/$enddate/p" /var/log/auth.log > result.txt

#Display the result column wise with highlighted searching key word
column -t result.txt | more

echo -e "---------* End of Search Result! *-----------"
```

Comment: A word of warning: If  either`$enddate` or `$startdate` is not found, nothing will be returned by `sed`.

Comment: You are right, it would be good to elaborate the text, so that the date is input in the right format to find right away!

Comment: That starts with the first line of `$startdate`, as you would expect, but stops with the first (not the last) line of `$enddate`.